# Vue.js not updating DOM with TextTrackCueList

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, html5-video

I want to iterate elements of a `TextTrackCueList`, which is basically an array of captions of a HTML5 video (for reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextTrack#Properties). Here is a simplified code:

```js
new Vue ({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      vid: null,
      track: null,
      cues: []
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.vid = this.$refs.vid;
    this.track = this.vid.addTextTrack("captions");
    this.track.mode = "showing";
    this.cues = this.track.cues;
    this.addCue(); //We add just one cue before the list is rendered
  },
  methods: {
    addCue() {
      let i = this.cues.length;
      //The cue just shows during one second
      let cue = new VTTCue(i, i+1, "Caption "+i);
      this.track.addCue(cue);
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.cues-list {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <video ref="vid" width="50%" src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ElephantsDream.mp4" controls></video>
  <div class="cues-list">
    <ul>
      <li v-for="cue in cues">
        {{ cue.text }}
      </li>
    </ul>
    <button @click="addCue">Add cue</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

As we can see, the list of `cues` is not updated when we add new cues. The reason I'm suspecting is that I'm not using one of the mutation methods overridden by Vue.js (https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Mutation-Methods), so the DOM is not updated automatically. Indeed, I'm using `TextTrack.addCue()` to add a cue, and not `Array.push()`, because the `TextTrack.cues` property is read-only. Is there a workaround, like for example a way to update manually the virtual DOM?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only answer I found was to force Vue to re-render:

```
addCue() {
  let i = this.cues.length;
  //The cue just shows during one second
  let cue = new VTTCue(i, i+1, "Caption "+i);
  this.track.addCue(cue);
  this.$forceUpdate();
}
```